# Cannot get the error.message (status 400+)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using node+express in my backend, and react on front. In node, I send the client a 400 error response:

```
return res.status(400).send("Invalid username!")
```

And in react, I call this api through axios with this:

```
await axios.post(url, user)
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
            console.log("logged!")
        }
        else {
            console.log(res)
        }
    })
```

When I purposely enter the wrong credentials for the object `user`, it would give me the `400 (Bad Request)` error. However, I cannot get the `invalid username` message. I look on the Network panel (Chrome) and there I could see the message. How do I get that message response?

I tried:

```
res.message
res.error
res.errors
res.body
```

Nothing worked. Thanks a lot!

But

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you're mixing `async/await` syntax with `.then/.catch`. It doesn't work like that, you need to do one or the other.

Secondly, that's not the right way to catch errors when using the `.then/.catch` syntax, you need the `.catch` method to catch those errors. If you want to use `async/await`, then you need to use a try/catch block.

So it needs to be like this:

```
axios.post(url, user)
    .then(res => {
      console.log("logged!")
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
```

Or like this:

```
try {
  const response = await axios.post(url, user);
  console.log(response);
}
catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for heads up. When I console.log the `err` it gives me the summary of the error like `Error: Request failed with status code 400`. I tried `err.message` and it says something like `Request failed with status code 400`. `err.data` and `err.body` both returned `undefined`.

Comment: I still can't get the `Invalid username!` message from my api

Comment: Try to send your response like this:  res.status(400).json({msg: "Invalid username"})  i.e. use res.json instead of res.send